# C# - logical operators with 2 variables - combining operators to avoid if-statements

Tags: c#, logical-operators

I have the following table of 2 boolean values.

I call one row from the left to the right statements.

```
a        b       result
------------------------
false    false   false
false    true    false
true     false   false
true     true    true
```

Now I have to write code so that all these results happen.

I might be able to solve that, by using some if-statements, switch-command and logical operators.

Is it possible to create a single - heaps complex - expression of logical operators.

Something like:

```
(a^b)||(a&&b)&(a??b)
```

..(this is obv just an example, so that u can understand what i'm AFTER)

Further question:

Is there any software that is able to create multiple randomly arranged boolean statements(for 2 variables)?

What will be the limits of such a software?
(and how does the number of rows/statements effect the number of possible solutions that may suit as an expression, consisting of logical operators)

Answer (score 0):

It is always possible to resolve any number of boolean variables and states into a [canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form_%28Boolean_algebra%29). For only 2 variables, though, it's easier to just keep a lookup table with the 16 possible results and use as required.

Comment: sorry mate, i dont want to be rude, but i doubt u understood the problem properly.
i'm looking for an expression, in canonical form (thanks for that). that matches these 4 states in the table above in one hit. and also how many possible canonical forms are for doing so. is there any software?

Comment: The entry that matches that specific truth table in the table of 16 for 2-variable expressions would contain `a && b`.

Comment: hi there, thanks for the effort, but i'm not happy with the answer yet